# Funciones onclick en a href - PHP - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, funciones, dom

Tengo el siguiente código en un formulario, pertenece a una columna de una tabla con datos recogidos de una base de datos MySQL.

```
echo "<td width=\"08%\" id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>
<!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. -->
    <center>
    <?php
        $estado = 1;
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='return cambiar_estado(".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO'].");'\">";
              echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
        echo "</a>";
        ?>
    </center>
    <?php 
echo "</td>";
```

Ahora tengo la siguiente función, en la cual haciendo click sobre cada elemento ID de la columna estado de la tabla, pondría una imagen x.gif, o pongamos de serie un texto "Hemos pulsado sobre esta imagen" para probar.

```
<script language="Javascript">
function cambiar_estado() {
    var img = "";
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
    if (pregunta == true) {
        mg = "<center><img src='imagenes/0.gif'/></center>";
    } else {
        tmg = "<center><img src='imagenes/2.gif'/></center>";
    }
    document.getElementById("estado" +id).innerHTML = img;
}
</script>
```

Lo que quiero es que si de inicio todas las filas (todos los usuarios) tienen el estado=1, me deje clickear para preguntarle: ¿Deseas cambiar el estado=0 o estado=2? Y automáticamente llame a la imagen. Eso ya lo tengo hecho, pero... 
Edito la pregunta: He leído que no se pueden cambiar las opciones del alert o del confirm() - Cancelar ó Aceptar -, sólo si se usan plugins o jQuery. ¿Es así?

---

¿Por qué con el siguiente código no me funciona la función? Eso sí, no me da fallos en la consola... qué raro no debe coger el "id".

```
function cambiar_estado(id) {
    var imagen = "";
    //alert("El ID elegido es: "+id);
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
    if (id == '1') {
        if (pregunta == true) {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/0.gif\"></center>";
        } else {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/2.gif\"></center>";
    } else if (id == '0') {
        if (pregunta == true) {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/1.gif\"></center>";
        } else {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/2.gif\"></center>";
    } else {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/0.gif\"></center>";
        } else {
            imagen = "<center><img src=\"/imagenes/1.gif\"></center>";
    }
    document.getElementById("estado" +id).innerHTML = imagen;
}
```

Comment: No veo en tu codigo el elemento que tenga el valor "id" en el atributo `id`

Comment: El valor es: id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" para cada fila.

Comment: el comando `document.getElementById` trae un elemento que tenga la id indicada en `id`, tienes que poner el valor y no el atributo

Comment: `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = texto;` está seleccionando un elemento con id = id, literalmente. Tendrás que pasarle a la función `cambiar_estado()` el propio objeto de esta manera `cambiar_estado(this)`, para luego acceder a su elemento padre ahí ya tienes el elemento. O simplemente pasarle el texto del estado... En definitiva, no estás seleccionando el elemento que crees estar seleccionando.

Comment: document.getElementById("id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\").innerHTML = texto; ¿a esto te refieres?

Comment: @Muriano si envia `this` dentro de la funcion no funcionara, ya que enviara el <a>

Comment: Creo que la función está bien, sólo que estoy pasando mal el valor ID y estoy pasándole simplemente el id de la etiqueta y no su valor propiamente dicho.

Comment: @sioesi, puede acceder al nodo padre del <a> con `this.parentElement`, por ejemplo.

Comment: el valor del id confundes con "id", deberias poner asi : document.getElementById(5).innerHTML = texto;

Comment: pero "document.getElementById(5).innerHTML = texto;" sería exclusivamente para el 5 y no para el clikeado.

Comment: @omaza1990 reemplaza el 5 con los id de tu bd, hace una consulta, obten los id de tu bd y genera con esos ids.

Comment: La consulta ya la tengo hecha:
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_obligatorios JOIN usuarios_datos ON usuarios_obligatorios.ID_OBLIGATORIO = usuarios_datos.ID_OBLIGATORIO ORDER BY usuarios_obligatorios.ID_OBLIGATORIO ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

por eso tenía en el ID --> id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\"

Comment: deberia ser algo asi, \"estado".$row[$result.id']."\ y luego llamarlo  con document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = texto;

Comment: Edité... ¿Por qué no me funciona la función, no la detecta al hacer click sobre las imágenes, debe estar NO cogiendo el valor de "id"? Pero al hacer un alert(id), si me muestra el seleccionado.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba hacer estos cambios:

- Pasa por parámetro el ID del registro en la función `cambiar_estado`

  ```
  <?php
  echo "<td width=\"08%\" id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>
  <!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. -->
      <center>
      <?php
          $estado = 1;
          echo "<a href='#' onclick='return cambiar_estado(".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO'].");'\">"; // Pasamos el ID
                echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
          echo "</a>";
      ?>
      </center>
  <?php 
  echo "</td>"; ?>
  ```
- Modifica la función javascript `cambiar_estado`, para que acepte el ID por parametro.

  ```
  <script language="Javascript">
  // Recibe ID 
  function cambiar_estado(id) {
      var texto = "";
      var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
      if (pregunta == true) {
          texto = "¡Has presionado OK!";
      } else {
          texto = "¡Has presionado Cancelar!";
      }

      // Buscamos el DOMElement con id="estado[ID]"
      document.getElementById("estado" + id).innerHTML = texto;
  }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: elimino la mia y me quedo con esta respuesta +1

Comment: @sioesi tu respuesta funcionaba y, aunque pienses que ésta puede ser mejor, la tuya también tiene sus ventajas y puede quedarse como alternativa porque le funcionará a otro usuario. No haría falta borrarla. Hay muchas maneras de hacer lo que OP busca, no hay por qué limitarse a una.

Comment: Ambas funcionaban. Muchas gracias, voy a darle un par de vueltas a la solución, y la intentaré hacer por mi cuenta. Así se aprende, de los errores...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la reabri por si sirve, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es que el click sea en el `<td>` para obtener el valor de el atributo `id`.

```
<td onclick="cambiar_estado(this);" width=\"08%\" id=\"estado".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">
```

Y la funcion

```
<script language="Javascript">
function cambiar_estado(row) {
    var texto = "";
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
    if (pregunta == true) {
        texto = "¡Has presionado OK!";
    } else {
        texto = "¡Has presionado Cancelar!";
    }
    row.innerHTML = texto;
}
</script>
```

Y para obtener la id solo basta con `row.id`

Comment: Una vez que me funciona y lo entendí, edité la pregunta para ver si hay una solución referente a mi nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Has puesto:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = texto;
```

Cuando en realidad necesitas elegir el id al que quieres que afecte:

```
document.getElementById("ID_AL_QUE_AFECTAR").innerHTML = texto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a poner una alternativa en la que se evita poner código JavaScript *inline* (directamente en las etiquetas HTML), algo que es recomendable porque es importante tratar de separar la interfaz de la funcionalidad, y porque si tienes los eventos *inline* entonces no puedes asociar más de uno.

La idea entonces sería quitar los `onclick` de las etiquetas `a` y añadir los controladores de evento con `addEventListener` en el JavaScript. Otra ventaja de este método es que ya no te tienes por qué preocupar de pasar IDs, puedes utilizar `this` que en ese contexto será el elemento que se ha pulsado (el `a`).

El código se vería así:

```js
// lees todos los enlaces que hay dentro de las celdas con id comenzando por "estado"
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("td[id^=estado] a");

// para cada uno de esos enlaces
for (let x = 0; x < enlaces.length; x++) {
  
  // añade un controlador del evento click
  enlaces[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    // que realiza todo tu código
    var texto = "";
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Qué deseas elegir?");
    if (pregunta == true) {
      texto = "OK";
    } else {
      texto = "Cancelar";
    }
    
    // puedes usar this para hacer referencia al elemento pulsado
    this.innerHTML = texto;
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="08%" id="estado0">
      <center>
        <a href='#'>
          <img src="/imagenes/1.gif" />
        </a>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td width="08%" id="estado1">
      <center>
        <a href='#'>
          <img src="/imagenes/1.gif" />
        </a>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td width="08%" id="estado2">
      <center>
        <a href='#'>
          <img src="/imagenes/1.gif" />
        </a>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td width="08%" id="estado3">
      <center>
        <a href='#'>
          <img src="/imagenes/1.gif" />
        </a>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```